# Al subir datos con acentos en postgresql se distorsionan, como lo soluciono?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, postgresql

Ã±
Ã¡
Ã©
Ã
Ã³
Ãº

Ya cambie todo a utf8 y no funciona

Comment: Hola slvdr alfaro, esta pregunta ha sido reportada por la comunidad como de baja calidad por su extensión y contenido. Por favor edítala para añadir más información que sirva para concretarla: ¿qué has cambiado a utf8: el campo, la tabla, la base de datos? ¿cómo lo cambiaste? ¿tienes un ejemplo que pueda servir de referencia para ayudarte? Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] donde encontraras consejos para mejorar tus publicaciones y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

al crear tu base de datos

utf8-ci
general-utf-8

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, esta publicación ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Por favor, edítala para añadir más detalles que puedan ayudar a resolver el problema: ¿se puede cambiar la colación una vez creada la base de datos? ¿cómo se haría? ¿podría indicarse la colación a un nivel más granular (tabla, columna)? Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] donde encontrarás recomendaciones para mejorar tus respuestas, y con ello ganarás una nueva medalla. Saludos.